# Add attachment to bug via bugzproxy

Tags: c#, bugzilla

I'm using 'bugzproxy' (a c# wrapper) to add a bug to Bugzilla. But I can't find a way for adding an attachment to a newly created bug or adding an attachment by editing an old bug. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bugzproxy) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method in bugzproxy. I had to write it myself - in the same way as the method for sending the bug is written.